# How to use ORecordHook in OrientDB version 1.7.x

Tags: java, orientdb

The current documentation / javadoc does not explain the use of the new methods in this interface:

- void onUnregister()
- ORecordHook.DISTRIBUTED_EXECUTION_MODE getDistributedExecutionMode()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- onUnregister() is called when the hook is unregistered
- getDistributedExecutionMode() is where to execute the hook: TARGET_NODE against the node that execute the operation, SOURCE_NODE the node that send the command, BOTH for both

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I am not clear enough. Your answer was already clear for me based on the method names. However, what is not clear for me is the use case of these methods. I am missing an example. Especially the *real* meaning / usage of DistributedExecutionMode is not clear for me (googling just gives me 3 pages without the needed information).

Comment: In distributed mode a trigger/hook can be executed on the node that get the request and/or all the nodes. That's the DistributedExecutionMode.